# How do I find a mongodb document where no embedded document or array element matches conditions?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given this:

```
{ _id: 1, results: [ {a: 82, b: 81}, {a: 82, b: 88} ] }
{ _id: 2, results: [ {a: 82, b: 90}, {a: 82, b: 33} ] }
```

I want to find the docs which have *no* results with a or b less than 80.  (doc 1 in this case)  I know I could use $elemMatch to find the docs with any result containing an a or b less than 80. Is there a way to do the reverse?

Alternatively, I could rewrite my conditions to find docs where *all* results have a and b greater than 79.  Is there an operator which does that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$not` and `$or`:

```
db.test.find({ "results" : { 
    "$not" : { 
        "$elemMatch" : { 
            "$or" : [
                { "a" : { "$lt" : 80 } }, 
                { "b" : { "$lt" : 80 } } 
             ]
         } 
     } 
} })
```

The negation of your condition is "documents with some result having `a` or `b` values less than 80". I wrote a query for that, and negated it. Given the way queries work on array elements, I believe it is generally necessary to use `$not` to enforce a condition on every array element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the opposite of `$lt` is `$gt`, which returns all documents that have a certain attribute greater than the specified value.

```
db.collection.find({results: {$elemMatch: { $and: [{a: {$gt: 79}}, {b: {$gt: 79}}]}}});
```

**EDIT**: I have further investigated and it appears that `$elemMatch` only checks the first element of the array. I have also checked the solution provided by *wdberkeley* and it works just as intended. Apart from the query built by *wdberkeley*, the only alternative would be to use the aggregation framework, but that would be far more complex  than a simple find query.

Comment: Wouldn't that find docs with at least one matching result?  I need the docs where _all_ results match.

Comment: @jeem My bad. I will further look into it and update the query with a valid solution.